# How to run quartz job on a only single host

Tags: java, timer, quartz-scheduler, jobs, job-scheduling

Currently we are using quartz timer in our application to execute a method everyday at midnight. Problem is, we will have it deployed on to multiple servers and we don't want each server firing off the job. We want only one server to fire off the job.

Since we are exposing via JMX, we could pause / shutdown the quartz timer on one of the hosts but that is not the desired solution.

Can we through code, have quartz job set to be executed on only one host?

Below is the xml we are using -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">

<bean id="timerJob"
class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
<property name="targetObject" value="com.x.y.TestClass" />
<property name="targetMethod" value="testMethod" />
 </bean>

<!-- Cron Trigger, runs every day at 2 AM -->
 <bean id="cronTrigger"  
class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
<property name="jobDetail" ref="timerJob" />
<property name="cronExpression" value="$timer.chronExpression}" />
```

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
<property name="jobDetails">
  <list>
    <ref bean="timerJob" />
  </list>
</property>
<property name="triggers">
  <list>
    <ref bean="cronTrigger" />
  </list>
</property>
<property name="quartzProperties">
  <util:properties>
    <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export">false</prop>
    <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.objectName">
      quartz:type=QuartzScheduler,name=TestClass
    </prop>
  </util:properties>
</property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28879397/java-quartz-scheduled-job-disallow-concurrent-execution-of-job

Answer (score 1):

You could use the autoStartup property of the SchedulerFactoryBean and the Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer (context:property-placeholder ...) to obtain the value of the flag from a JVM system property, or from a standard Java properties file on the classpath etc.

```
<bean id="scheduler"
  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
  ...
  <property name="autoStartup" value="${quartz.started}"/>
...
</bean>
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
<property name="autoStartup" ref="custom_factory_bean_that_reads_the_flag_from_app_cfg"/>
```

This would obviously affect all your jobs as they would all be executed only on hosts where autoStartup=true.

AFAIK Quartz API itself does not allow you to restrict execution of a particular job to a specific host/s.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a scheduler for only that machine. The scheduler will be responsible for scheduling the job.