# Java Quartz scheduled Job - disallow concurrent execution of Job

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler

I am using a Quartz Job for executing specific tasks.

I am also scheduling its execution in my Main application class and what i am trying to accomplish is not to allow simultaneous instances of this job to be executed.

So the scheduler should only execute the job if its previous instance is finished.

Here is my Job class:

```
public class MainJob implements Job {

static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MainJob.class.getName());

@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {

    GlobalConfig cfg = new GlobalConfig();

    ProcessDicomFiles processDicomFiles = new ProcessDicomFiles();  
    ProcessPdfReportFiles processPdf = new ProcessPdfReportFiles();

    try {

            log.info("1. ---- SCHEDULED JOB -- setStudiesReadyToProcess");
            processDicomFiles.setStudiesReadyToProcess();

            log.info("2. ---- SCHEDULED JOB --- distributeToStudies");
            processDicomFiles.distributeToStudies(cfg.getAssocDir());                

            ...

            //process any incoming PDF file
            log.info("11. ---- SCHEDULED JOB --- processPdfFolder");
            processPdf.processPdfFolder();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.ERROR, null, ex);
        }

    log.info(">>>>>>>>>>> Scheduled Job has ended .... <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");

    }
}
```

So in my application's main class i am starting the scheduler:

```
...
//start Scheduler
    try {             
        startScheduler();
    } catch (SchedulerException ex) {
        log.log(Level.INFO, null, ex);
    }
...

public void startScheduler () throws SchedulerException {

        //Creating scheduler factory and scheduler
        factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        scheduler = factory.getScheduler();

        schedulerTimeWindow = config.getSchedulerTimeWindow();

        JobDetailImpl jobDetail = new JobDetailImpl();
        jobDetail.setName("First Job");
        jobDetail.setJobClass(MainJob.class);

        SimpleTriggerImpl simpleTrigger = new SimpleTriggerImpl();
        simpleTrigger.setStartTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000));
        simpleTrigger.setRepeatCount(SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY);
        simpleTrigger.setRepeatInterval(schedulerTimeWindow);
        simpleTrigger.setName("FirstTrigger");

        //Start scheduler
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail,simpleTrigger);

}
```

I would like to prevent scheduler from starting a second MainJob instance if another one is still running ...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just use the `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` Annotation on top of the Job class.

See this official [example](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz-scheduler.org-site/blob/master/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/examples/Example4.md#colorjob-example4-colorjob) or this [tutorial](http://jayvilalta.com/blog/2014/06/04/understanding-the-disallowconcurrentexecution-job-attribute/) about concurrent job execution.

Comment: Still looking for a way that doesn't queue up the job, and instead just skips it.

Answer (score 8):

`@DisallowConcurrentExecution` can do your job but please consider that it would only prevent your class from being run twice on the same node.

Please see @ReneM comment in [Quartz 2.2 multi scheduler and @DisallowConcurrentExecution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35292420/quartz-2-2-multi-scehduler-and-disallowconcurrentexecution/35296259#35296259)

Comment: Where did you get that from? Reading the linked comment, it seems that what he is saying is that DisallowConcurrentExecution will only work if you ahve clustering properly setup. Not that it doesn't work across nodes.

Answer (score 5):

You can implement [StatefulJob](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/StatefulJob.html) or annotate [DisallowConcurrentExecution](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/DisallowConcurrentExecution.html)

Comment: StatefulJob is deprecated (dont know if it was 05.2015). DisallowConcurrentExecution and/or PersistJobDataAfterExecution is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Be cereful when execute from Job with `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` method with `@Async`

The *second thread* may conflict with the *first*

Comment: What will happen if second thread may conflict with the first? Do you mean Execute method is async will have such conflict?

Comment: I think this shows how to do async and DisallowConcurrentExecution https://damienbod.com/2021/11/08/asp-net-core-scheduling-with-quartz-net-and-signalr-monitoring/

Comment: @SaigeZhang If the business logic in the `@Async` method will take a long time to execute, and `Job` is executed frequently (ex `CRON: '0/10 * * ? * *'` ), this may result in two async threads changing the same data.
You will have to explicitly set for Job which tasks are already in progress