# Quartz 2.2 multi scheduler and @DisallowConcurrentExecution

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Please consider this example.

A sample web application calls `scheduler.start()` on its start up. The scheduler configured to store its jobs in DB.

The application is copied on six web-servers.

So if we start six web-servers we will have six scheduler with same name on a single DB. As mentioned in https://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/cookbook/MultipleSchedulers:

> Never start (scheduler.start()) a non-clustered instance against the same set of database tables that any other instance with the same scheduler name is running (start()ed) against. You may get serious data corruption, and will definitely experience erratic behavior.

So this will fail.

My question is that if I am sure that all of my jobs have `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` will above work or it will still fail ?!

---

If `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` does not help, I should do it manually configure one server as some how Master

```
public class StartUp implements ServletContextListener {

   public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
       if(THIS_IS_MASTER_TOMCAT){
         scheduler.start()
       }
}
```

Are there better ways?!

Comment: The DissallowConcurrentExecution would only prevent your class been run twice on same node. When you only start the scheduler on one node, this node will be the only one scheduling something. What you need is a Quartz cluster setup where every scheduler has  unique name. There is a way to say quartz so generate the nodename on startup. I'm not totaly sure about this all, because my last quartz using project is long time ago, but it was clustered ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically Rene M. is correct. Here are the docs in question vis-a-vis Quartz:

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering.html

Now some background and a conceptual example from our own use at my company. We use quartz clustering mode *within* a Wildfly Cluster. That is each wildfly cluster node runs quartz. Since quartz is running in cluster mode itself and is pointed at the same database schema we are guaranteed to run one job per *cluster*. Again, see the documentation. The key issues are this:

1. A single quartz cluster must run against a single quartz database
   schema. You obviously must create the relational database tables per
   the documentation. No biggie.
2. You must set the quartz.property files
   properly and a copy of which must exist for each node in the
   cluster. *The same exact quartz.property file*
3. Lastly you must use a NonJTA datasource otherwise the quartz cluster will fail. That often means in Wildfly world quartz
   will require its own
       datasource.

quartz.property example:

```
    #============================================================================
# Configure Main Scheduler Properties 
#============================================================================

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = BjondScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO

#============================================================================
# Configure ThreadPool 
#============================================================================

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 5

#============================================================================
# Configure JobStore 
#============================================================================

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 5000

org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction = true
org.quartz.scheduler.userTransactionURL = java:jboss/UserTransaction

org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = PostgreSQLDS
org.quartz.jobStore.nonManagedTXDataSource = PostgreSQLDSNoJTA

org.quartz.dataSource.PostgreSQLDSNoJTA.jndiURL=java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDSNoJTA
org.quartz.dataSource.PostgreSQLDS.jndiURL=java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDS


#============================================================================
# Configure Logging
#============================================================================
#org.quartz.plugin.jobHistory.class=org.quartz.plugins.history.LoggingJobHistoryPlugin
#org.quartz.plugin.jobHistory.jobToBeFiredMessage=Bjond Job [{1}.{0}] to be fired by trigger [{4}.{3}] at: {2, date, HH:mm:ss MM/dd/yyyy} re-fire count: {7}
#org.quartz.plugin.jobHistory.jobSuccessMessage=Bjond Job [{1}.{0}] execution complete and reports: {8}
#org.quartz.plugin.jobHistory.jobFailedMessage=Bjond Job [{1}.{0}] execution failed with exception: {8}
#org.quartz.plugin.jobHistory.jobWasVetoedMessage=Bjond Job [{1}.{0}] was vetoed. It was to be fired by trigger [{4}.{3}] at: {2, date, dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS}
```

Now our datasource snippet within standalone.xml:

```
            <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDSNoJTA" pool-name="PostgreSQLDSNoJTA" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
```

You fill in the rest of this datasource element per your requirements. The @DisallowConcurrentExecution is a good idea to prevent multiple jobs on a single node form executing a particular method but it is the quartz clustering that prevents the same job running on multiple VM's; not this annotation.