# how to prevent quartz from running another job if the previous one is still running?

Tags: quarkus, quartz

I'm using Quarkus. My Quartz jobs are scheduled to run every 10 seconds:

```
        return TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("my-job")
                .startNow() 
                .withSchedule(
                        SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                                .withIntervalInSeconds(10)
                                .repeatForever()
                ).build();
```

This works fine but jobs keep triggering every 10 seconds irrespective of whether or not the last one finishes. I need the next job to start only if there are no jobs currently running job. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/28880097/175554 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add @DisallowConcurrentExecution on you Job class.

as example :

```
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class MyScheduledJob implements Job {
 //execution method
}
```